# Output EOF using %f

Tags: c, io, printf, eof, format-specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d",EOF);
}
```

generates -1 which is totally fine, but

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f",EOF);
}
```

produces 0.000 . How can someone explain this when the expected output is -1.000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a wrong format specifier for any particular argument in `printf()` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`EOF` is of type `int`. You can only use `%d` for an `int` type variable.

FWIW, if you want a floating point representation of an `int`, you have to `cast` the variable (but I personally recommend to avoid this)

```
printf("%f",(float)EOF);
```

Comment: And most compilers are able to warn you (e.g. compile the offending code with `gcc -Wall`)

Answer (score 5):

`EOF` is of `int` (`signed`) type. You should not use wrong format specifier to print `int`, otherwise it will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @YuHao Yes, i think you're correct. I don;t remember where, but I have seen somewhere using `%d` to print EOF. I believe that was correct (none objected).

Comment: @YuHao; Sorry. That was typo. I mean `signed` of course.